# Typographic Alignment in WideImage PHP

Tags: php, text, alignment, wideimage

How to align the text in WideImage plugin in PHP?

For example, Left Alignment should be like this:

```
Sample Text Here.
Sample Text.
Sample.
```

Right alignment:

```
Sample Text Here.
     Sample Text.
            Text.
```

Center Alignment should:

```
Sample Text Here.
  Sample Text.
Sample Text Here.
```

The plugin can only coordinate the text but not the alignment.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: P.S I am using textarea html tag... to be able to break a line... and no need to work on left alignment because it is default... my problem is how to code right alignment and center alignment in wideimage PHP after the form is submitted.